# MAVEN Build failure do to node permission denied

Tags: java, maven, npm, build, aem

While building my project in my local I am getting a Build Failure for UI apps, seems to be related to NPM.
Not sure if its related to Node or to some Java issues regarding the JDK. Any info on this very issue?

Is there some internal permissions configs I must change?

```
sh: /Users/test.gc/Desktop/git/test-dot-com/test-dot-com/ui.apps/node_modules/.bin/npm-run-all: Permission denied

[ERROR] Command execution failed.

org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 126 (Exit value: 126)

    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)

    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)

    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:804)

    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:751)

    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:313)

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)

    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)

    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)

    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)

    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)

    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)

    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)

    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)

    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)

    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)

    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Reactor Summary for jll-dot-com 21.5.0:

[INFO] 

[INFO] jll-dot-com ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.246 s]

[INFO] jll-dot-com - Core ................................. SUCCESS [ 15.429 s]

[INFO] jll-dot-com - Groovy Console Extension ............. SUCCESS [  0.933 s]

[INFO] jll-dot-com - UI apps .............................. FAILURE [  8.991 s]

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time:  26.590 s

[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-10T08:57:09-07:00

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (npm-run-build) on project jll-dot-com.ui.apps: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 126 (Exit value: 126) -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :jll-dot-com.ui.apps
```

What are the steps to complete this build with no failures.

Comment: If you execute the command with the user that checked out the files, you should have no issue. Check with `ls -la` to see who owns the directory. Also, try deleting the node_modules directory and let the maven build to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sh: /Users/test.gc/Desktop/git/test-dot-com/test-dot-com/ui.apps/node_modules/.bin/npm-run-all: Permission denied
```

The first line says it all.

I suggest you try to run the same command in the code repo with npm directly and see what kind of permission you are getting.

```
npx npm-run-all
```

Each file has 3 attributes: Read, Write, and Execute

```
total 0
0 drwx------@  6 samuel  staff   192 Apr 27 17:28 Applications
```

It is likely you do not have permission to execute the file. This can be caused by many possible reasons. For example, if you download, then copy and paste them. If the permission issue is indeed caused by insufficient permission, change the permission by using the following command.

```
chmod +x YOUR_REPO_DIR/.bin/*
```

This will grant the execution permission to the commands.

Comment: where should i add this command ? "chmod +x /.bin/*
"

Comment: i get not matches found when running that command

Comment: once you are in your code repo directory, do the command `chmod +x .bin/*` (Sorry made a typo earlier)